# Orientation in android emulator

Tags: android, orientation

I first choose default orientation from my emulator. Then i choose to view landscape and it works. But again when i turn my emulator into default orientation then i find that my application orientation doesn't change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
   >
```

Comment: i have gone through many website but didn't find any valuable information.

Comment: Don't comment, instead edit your own question.

Comment: android Emulator is bad. You should run your app in real device.

Comment: sorry but i do not have an android device .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue that sometimes appears in emulator version 2.3 I solved this problem by running the application on 4.0

Answer (score 2):

press home button of your emulator and make your emulator to default orientation after run your application again

Answer (score 0):

See if your application's manifest contains the following:

```
<activity... android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Remove this attribute. It locks the app into a specific orientation. However, when you do, your activity will be deleted and recreated every time orientation changes (potentially loading a different layout file). To handle the change of orientation without activity restart, add the following attribute to the `<activity>`

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: yes i have android:configChanges="orientation" in my application